# Bubble Diagram inside a Bubble Diagram

Tags: smartdiagram

Is it possible to make a bubble diagram within a bubble diagram? If not, is it possible with the constellation diagram?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A bubble diagram is AFAIK not a unique object. Please provide us with some information (like a sketch) of what you are looking for. Or are you looking for a mindmap?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! From the `smartdiagram` tag I guessed that you use this package and I copied the bubble diagram example from the package manual as a starting point for my answer. Next time you ask a question, it would be helpful if you provide such an example yourself as part of your question text (could be an example from a manual or one that you write yourself, as long as it is small and self-contained). That would eliminate the guessing and would allow answerers to reproduce and address the issue immediately without needing to do preparation [...]

Comment: [...] and will attract faster and better answers (and upvotes for your question in case you are interested in that).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible - I've tried it :)

In the example below I used a `\resizebox` to make the nested diagram smaller, and I added a `\Huge` font switch within the nested diagram to make the text a bit more readable. Also I increased the distance between the bubbles a bit to avoid overlap.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{distance center/other bubbles=1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
Build a program,Set up,Run,{\resizebox{3cm}{!}{\Huge \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
Bubbles,So,Much,Bubbles%
}}},Modify,Check
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]